# Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED React native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native facing some issues

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> 15 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 13 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 21s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 21s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\RDX\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\RDX\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\RDX\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\RDX\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 2):

More information is needed here but you can try the following quick fixes.

> Please note that the below terminal commands are based on Mac and Linux operating systems.

> Run `npx react-native run-android` after each command below to see which fix works for you.

#### FIX-1:: Clean stale build & start a fresh one

```
  cd ./android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```

#### FIX-2:: Re-install project packages

```
  rm -rf ./node_modules
  npm install or yarn install
```

#### FIX-3:: Update your Gradle (Gradle is an android build system).

1. Run this command again,

   ```
     cd ./android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
   ```
2. Update distributionUrl on android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to,

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

3. Update gradle tools version on android/build.gradle

   ```
   buildscript {
     ...
     dependencies {
         ...
         classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0') // Use this verison
   ```

NOTE: Each command above should be executed from the project root folder.
If none of these works then please leave a comment!

Comment: Where did you take this command from "rm"? It doesn't recognize it

Comment: It is a built-in Terminal command in Mac and Linux. Not sure if it works in Windows.